# Where is the menu for changing page numbering hierarchy?

Tags: microsoft-word

So last time I was using Word you could open a window in which you would have all your current page numbering shown and you could choose to move an item deeper or higher up the numbering hierarchy. It was 10x better than manually choosing a lever for each title/header because somehow I break it every time.

This way I would first put all the titles/headers on the level 1 and then just move some items down.

How do I get to this menu?

Answer (score 0):

see this instruction .pdf from andrews.edu website where they describe it in more detail than i could explain.

[HOW TO PAGE A DOCUMENT](https://www.andrews.edu/library/RefDesk/HOW%20TO%20PAGE%20A%20DOCUMENTversion%20II.pdf)

Please let me know if this worked for you :)